# How to get Springer two column latex template

Tags: latex3

I'm trying to find the latex template for this journal Pattern Recognition and Image Analysis, which requires articles in Two columns. I have checked all over their website https://www.pleiades.online/en/journal/patrec/authors-instructions/ in order to find the latex template.
no link shared!!!

The Springer https://www.springer.com/gp/livingreviews/latex-templates has this template of only one column: LaTeX Macro Package **[all journals]**

Really, I'm confused.

My question is where can I find the template of two columns of this journal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the link that you shared, you can download the template (the official one). This has everything you need.

There is a line within the template that you need to uncomment to make the journal a two column format. (line 41 to 44)

```
%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
```

just comment the 3rd line and uncomment the 4th.

If you are new to Latex, make sure you check how to use it first. It will save you a lot of time and efforts in the end.

Comment: Sadly https://www.springer.com/gp/livingreviews/latex-templates removed the svjour3 format :-(